# Comparing each set of a two-dimensional array to determine largest distance

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, euclidean-distance

So I have a set of elements in a 2d array, and I am trying to determine the largest distance between coordinates.

I have made a loop to go through each element, but I can't figure out how to only compare the first set, with the second and so on. I have been trying different methods for a couple days now and this is what I've gotten so far.

using the formula:
       furthestDistance = Math.sqrt((Math.pow((maxX - minX), 2))+ 
         (Math.pow((maxY-minY), 2)));

```
int max = cities[0][0]; //int to store the max of the i column
  int min = cities[0][0]; //int to store the max of the i column


  int maxX = cities[0][0]; //int to store the max of the i column
  int maxY = cities[0][0]; //int to store the max of the i column

  int minX = cities[0][0]; //int to store the max of the j column
  int minY = cities[0][0]; //int to store the max of the j column




 for(int y=1; y<cities[0].length; y++) { //loop through columns
       for(int x=0; x<cities[y].length; x++) { //loop through lines


            if(cities[x][y] > max) { //if the number at the column i and line j is bigger than max

                max = cities[x][y];
                maxX = cities[x][0];
                maxY = cities[0][y];
            }
            if(((cities[x][0])  < min) && (cities[0][y] < min)) { //if the number at the column i and line j is bigger than max
                min = cities[x][y];

                minX = cities[x][0];
                minY = cities[0][y];

            }


        }
    }
 System.out.println("the maxX is " +maxX+ " the minX is " + maxY);
 System.out.println("the maxX is " +minX+ " the minX is " + minY);



    }


}
```

for the example array i have:
int[][] cities = {{-48,-4},{23,-45},{-7,-40},{-28,31},{36,24},{23,-11},{36,-10},{-9,21}};

and the expected output should be about 91.5259.
Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understood it well, you just have do a double for loop to evaluate the distance between each pair of city (i,j) and update the maximum distance if it is higher. This can be done easily:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int[][] cities = {{-48,-4},{23,-45},{-7,-40},{-28,31},{36,24},{23,-11},{36,-10},{-9,21}};

    double maxDistance = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < cities.length-1; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < cities.length; j++) {
            maxDistance = Math.max(getDistance(cities[i], cities[j]), maxDistance);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The max distance is " + maxDistance);
}

private static double getDistance(int[] city1, int[] city2) {
    int dx = city1[0] - city2[0];
    int dy = city1[1] - city2[1];
    return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}
```

Note that `j` goes from `i+1` to `cities.length` because you only need to check the [unordered pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unordered_pair) (i,j) since distance(i,j) == distance (j,i).

---

Java 8 alternative:

```
double maxDistance  = Arrays.stream(cities)
        .flatMapToDouble(city1 -> Arrays.stream(cities).mapToDouble(city2 -> getDistance(city1, city2)))
        .max()
        .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new); //Or any other exception
```

Comment: Also, don't bother with the sqrt. The greatest square of the distance is still the greatest distance.